# Default type=email validation being ignored

Tags: html, validation, angular-material2

I'm building an Angular Material registration form.  One of the input elements is type=email.

The expected behavior is, on submit, if the email is not in proper email format the form will not be valid and I will get a default browser error, seen here:

[image: Email Error]

[Code pen to test desired behavior](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzBLwq)

However, that's not what's happening at all.  I'm using Material components to build out the form:

```
<form class="form" [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field class="form-full">
        <input matInput placeholder="First Name" style="width:350px" formControlName="firstName" required />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="form-full">
        <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" style="width:350px" formControlName="lastName" required />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="form-full">
        <input matInput placeholder="Email" style="width:350px" type="email" formControlName="email" required />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="form-full">
        <input matInput placeholder="Password" style="width:350px" type="password" formControlName="password" required />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="form-full">
        <input matInput placeholder="Confirm Password" style="width:350px" type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword" required />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-raised-button mat-button color="primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</form>
```

My register.component.ts is very basic right now, as I just started building out the component.  I bind a form group to my registration form and console out some values in the onSubmit.

```
export class RegisterComponent {

  registerForm;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.registerForm = fb.group({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      confirmPassword: '',
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.registerForm.value);
    console.log(this.registerForm.valid);
  }

}
```

I expect registrationForm.valid to be false and a browser error to display when the submit button is pressed, however that is not happening.  Of course, I can validate this myself - but not getting desired behavior is driving me nuts.

Here are the results:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the EmailValidator Directive, just add **email** attribute to your input syntax.

```
 <input matInput placeholder="Email" style="width:350px" type="email" formControlName="email" email required />
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator

Comment: That is exactly what I did.  Still curious why the default behavior wasn't working.